# what is this Purple text between "{{" "}}"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I came across this code in Googles Web login example ([Here](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-csharp.git)) and I dont know why this is purple. 
I believe that it is some kind of global value, kinda like the Author item in Office. but if thats so, how do you set them? what is it even called?

[image: Purple Text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html file that you see there is read in by the application and the values that you see between the curly braces are replaced with values from the application.  Look at the c# code to see where this is happening.

https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-csharp/blob/master/gplus-quickstart-csharp/signin.ashx.cs

around line 117 you'll see where the values are replaced.

Answer (score 1):

the purple text is a placeholder to be replaced by the actual value. look at signin.ashx.cs for the following code:

```
static public string APP_NAME = "Google+ C# Quickstart";
//...
templatedHTML = Regex.Replace(templatedHTML, "[{]{2}\\s*APPLICATION_NAME\\s*[}]{2}", APP_NAME);
```